# What CMS can be used with Phalcon framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, phalcon, phalconeye

I've been using Wordpress for the past 4 years for developing small and medium websites. Now I have an enterprise project and I'm considering using [Phalcon PHP framework](http://phalconphp.com/en/).

My enterprise project will be handling a large amount of users and will be publishing articles with images. This is why I still want to use some sort of CMS.

I think framework like Phalcon is great for service and business layers, but it lacks the GUI / services found in various  CMS's like Wordpress. I know [Phalcon Eye](http://phalconeye.com/) is in development, but it's in very early development stage (I think).

Can Phalcon MVC be used alongside any CMS? If yes, wouldn't the speed of Phalcon bee compromised by much slower CMS? (And what CMS is recommended?)

**Update**
The first version of my enterprise project is currently using WP for handling user registration, page / template handling, articles etc. But that's just a small part of the solution. All other code is custom and I've realized that should use a solid framework like Phalcon, Laravel, Sympfony etc.

**Update 2**
What if I use a framework like Phalcon for my custom code, present data and form handling. Then I build a Wordpress service that will retrieve articles from WP DB's. That way I would not need to use wordpress for presentation, but I can use WP for handling articles, images and maybe even users. Bad idea?

Comment: PhalconEye is only one CMS in the market today. What I think is that after Phalcon project we can except more projects written as PHP extensions. Because if you can increase the performance this way, why not go one step further and develop, for example Wordpress as PHP extension written in C language. I think it is future of PHP.

Comment: The real question is: do you really need Phalcon? Sounds like a pretty high risk choice to me tbh.

Comment: It would be a smart choice to use a proper framework. I can use any framework, but Phalcon is new and super fast. This article highlights the good frameworks for 2014: http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-frameworks-2014/

Comment: @Steven yeah about that https://twitter.com/PHPeeHaa/status/419539693064052736. Popular !== good

Comment: I've never used any framework except WP CMS. Currently I'm looking into Phalcon and Yii (Yii because the company helping me is using it for their projects).

Comment: While considering phalcon - please think about framework updates. Updating a PHP extension on a production server is not that easy as updating only PHP files. Also - how fast can you update it if a major security issue appears? It's fast - yes, but has other problems. If you want really fast - just use node.js :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Yona CMS (built with Phalcon)](https://builtwith.phalcon.io/project/yonacms.com), whose [code is hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/alexander-torosh/yona-cms), with modular structure and great speed of Phalcon Framework.
There are few large projects working on this CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Using an existing CMS for the admin and writing a phalcon frontend for it is a very intriguing idea I have pondered on and off over the years. (I haven't done it yet because I have a custom CMS to maintain, which I am not sure how to replace with WP or joomla etc)

I think it would be possible to have a site that is much faster than a WP site by using phalcon, but I think the tradeoff is no WP plugins will work, and the more PHP you use to make them work, the more you erode the benefit of phalcon and you might have well just used WordPress.

I have never used Phalcon 2.0 with Zephir, so can't comment on that.

----- extra comment stuff----

I see a comment about updating phalcon, which I thought I would address you can update phalcon with 3 or 4 commands (or a single shell script), and it only takes affect when you restart your webserver. Apache can do a graceful restart which shouldn't affect any of your users.

Whether phalcon is harder to update than a framework written in PHP file comes down to your update method. Updating phalcon with git is far quicker, easier and safer than FTPing individual files for example. Naturally using git for both I don't see much of a difference, just as long as the webserver is clever enough to not open the php file just as you are copying it of course...

re: speed - phalcon is very fast (upto 10x faster than zend framework v1 IMO, YMMV), it might not be as fast as node depending on what you are doing, but if your PHP is far better than your JS and your Server Admin has never used node - like me then the difference in speed it didn't look like it was worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think as per your requirement you should go for a CMS, Phalcon does not provide you the functionalists of a CMS, it has it's own advantages. If you are using wordpress and not satisfied with its performance then there are many other popular CMS solutions available in PHP like Joomla or Drupal, you can look into that also, and choose the best that fits in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Only a CMS based on phalcon, like [phalconeye](https://github.com/PhalconEye/phalconeye), may get the benefits of phalcon's speed.

If you want speed, avoid Drupal, that not where it is the better.

Comment: But a CMS is not a framework like the ones I've mentioned. And the CMS part of the solution is rather small. I just like the GUI for handling pages / templates, users and articles.

Comment: The domain is on sale. is there a public repository for that CMS?